Getting customer catalog requests using REST API
Our company has a customer form that allows customers to put in a request for a printed catalog of our products.  While that information can be exported manually I want to be able to pull the information down via REST API, but I cannot find any reference material.
The data is being stored "somewhere" since a catalog request csv file is being created for download.
Perhaps how I am searching on the Web is not correct.  Does anyone using M2 know what API lets me "GET" customer catalog requests.  I'm okay once I know what endpoint to call.
